Disaggregating algebra formula
I have been trying to come up with a way to calculate the individual contribution of each row i. However due to the non-linear relationship implied by the power to 0.5 it is not as straight forward as initially forward. Any help on how I can come up with a calculation for the individual contribution of z for each row i so that the sum is still consistent?
$z=-(\sum_{i}(x_i))^{\frac{1}{2}}\times1.6449+\sum_{i}(y_i)$
Thanks in advance
